# Remove/clear previous buffer/stream video mpmovieplayer iphone

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, buffer, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing a video in my iPhone/iPad using mpmovieplayercontroller application and video size is very large (approx 2-3 hours). And application crashed after half played due to memory warning. So please can any one suggest how I clear/remove previously buffer video from memory.

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there is no need to clear/remove buffer video. Try running memory profiler to see if your code is not leaking.

Project menu > Profile -> Choose Memory Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

The memory warning occurs only in **simulator**. Try it in **device**. Will work fine, no issues. So you don't need to clear anything.
This happens because the **simulator** gives a bunch of false leaks (such as in AudioToolbox, CoreVideo, etc.). Ans the simulator seems to cache the entire video and not release it properly whereas the device buffers only what it needs along the way.
Hope that make sense